# send csrf_token with a ajax request

Tags: php

I need help to send the token with ajax request. He always say: "invalid".

What Mistake do I make?

world.php:

```
<form name="theform" id="suchform" method="POST">
    <p><input type="text" class="find_person search_btn" placeholder="Person Suchen" tabindex="1"></p>
    <p><input type="hidden" class="csrf_token" value="<?= echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>"></p>
</form>
<div id="output">
</div>
<script>
    $('#suchform').on('input', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#suchform').find('.find_person').val();
        var token = $('#suchform').find('.csrf_token').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'show_user.php',
            data: {find_person:name, csrf_token:token},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#output').html(data);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

show_user.php

```
if ($_POST['csrf_token'] !== $_SESSION['csrf_token']) {
    echo $_POST['csrf_token'] . '<br>' . $_SESSION['csrf_token']. '<BR>';
    exit("invalid");
}
```

connect.php

```
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
```